# Why fdisk -l shows the Ext4 as Microsoft basic data

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk, fdisk

I have dual boot machine (Ubuntu 16.04 + Windows 10). Today I was mounting a flash disk then I executed the command fdisk -l but I saw something weird.

> `Device             Start        End   Sectors  Size Type`

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     923647    921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2    923648    1128447    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1128448    1161215     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1161864  106029703 104867840   50G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 106031104  944902143 838871040  400G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 944902144  991815679  46913536 22.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p7 991815680 1000212479   8396800    4G Microsoft basic data
```

Why it say that the "nvme0n1p6" is Microsoft basic data although it's Ext4?
Also the "nvme0n1p6" show the same although it's SWAP.

Also nvme0n1p5 and nvme0n1p4 should be NTFS, why it is saying Microsoft basic data?

Is it normal that are some disks doesn't start exactly the next sector of the previous one?

[image: Screenshot of the GUI Disks tool showing the right disk type]

Thank You

Comment: Because you are using gpt partitioning table and an outdated version of libparted - http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/

Comment: See also - https://askubuntu.com/questions/703443/gdisk-hex-codes

Comment: @Panther according to "http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/" under "What's the problem?" these partitions should show up under Windows but they don't?.  Also you said I'm using an outdated "libparted".. I regulary check for update using Ubuntu software app and apt-get install update/upgrade .. shouldn't everything be up to date?

Comment: As far as "up to date" see https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software . As far as https://askubuntu.com/questions/703443/gdisk-hex-codes,  under "What's the problem?" Quote - "This means that Windows shows Linux filesystem partitions as unformatted disks in its file manager, and if you attempt to access one, Windows asks you if you want to format it, as shown below." I do not know the current affair of windows and linux partitions. but the link explains the behavior of fidsk on linux .

Comment: @Panther Thank you, I learned a lot from the links you provided.