# I need 2 create a partition on my USB flash drive with block/cluster size of 256 KB, but cant find the dialog box 2 specify this block size in Disks

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, fdisk, disk-management, gdisk

I'm using Gnome's Disks program 2 format my USB flash drive. I want only 1, [0700 Microsoft basic data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703443/gdisk-hex-codes) partition, covering the whole disk. The disk will be used to transfer 2-8GB video files between Windows and Linux computers.

I want exFAT file system on this partition.

It is important for me to specify the block/cluster size, because I'll have large files on this disk, so I want big clusters, not this small 4KB or 8KB clusters/blocks.

In Windows 10/11 there is a dialog box for setting this cluster/block size.

But I can't find the same dialog box in Disks program, that I'm using, to make this partitions and create this file systems.

[image]
[image]

Is it there, and if not, how can I create the filesystem I need (exFAT) with the block size I want (128KB or 256KB) using terminal.

Is there any difference if I use 'gdisk' over 'fdisk' or is it the same?

Comment: When you intend to use a Microsoft file system (exFAT), and Windows is available, I suggest that you use Windows to create it, to use native tools for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fdisk` and `gdisk` manipulate partition tables, these commands do not create filesystems. The correct command-line tool to create an exFAT filesystem is `mksf.exfat`.

In Ubuntu 22.04 and above `mkfs.exfat` is part of the package `exfatprogs`, in Ubuntu 20,04 it is part of the package `exfat-utils`.

You should also have the package `exfat-fuse` installed.

Please read the manual `man mkfs.exfat` after installation of the necessary packages, so you will be able to create the command up to yor needs.

Answer (score 1):

**mkexfatfs** - create an exFAT file system

**SYNOPSIS**

```
  mkexfatfs  [ -i volume-id ] [ -n volume-name ] [ -p partition-first-sector ] [ -s sectors-
   per-cluster ] [ -v ] device
```

**DESCRIPTION**

mkexfatfs creates an exFAT file system on a  block  device.   device  is  a  special  file
corresponding to the device.

**OPTIONS**

```
   Command line options available:

   -i volume-id
          A 32-bit hexadecimal number. By default a value based on current time is set.

   -n volume-name
          Volume name (label), up to 15 characters. By default no label is set.

   -p partition-first-sector
          First sector of the partition starting from the beginning of the whole disk.  exFAT
          super block has a field for this value but in  fact  it's  optional  and  does  not
          affect anything. Default is 0.

   -s sectors-per-cluster
          Number  of  physical  sectors per cluster (cluster is an allocation unit in exFAT).
          Must be a power of 2, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. Cluster size  can  not  exceed  32  MB.
          Default cluster sizes are: 4 KB if volume size is less than 256 MB, 32 KB if volume
          size is from 256 MB to 32 GB, 128 KB if volume size is 32 GB or larger.

   -v     Print version and copyright.
```

[mkexfatfs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mkexfatfs.8.html)